# Zuul proxy simple auth

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, netflix-zuul

I have simple spring boot app that proxy some api with zuul proxy

```
@EnableZuulProxy
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoClientApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoClientApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8080
zuul:
  routes:
    test:
      path: /api/**
      url: http://localhost:8081/api/
```

localhost:8081 has basic auth, something like

```
localhost:8081/j_spring_security_check?j_username=user&j_password=pass
```

that return me cookies with JSESSIONID and by setting up this JSESSIONID to header i can get resource. I cant change localhost:8081 because its not my service. How can I get this JSESSIONID and setting up to zuul? Can I do this just with yml?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about Sensitive Headers in the configuration options. By default, headers Cookie, Set-Cookie, Authorization are blocked by the `sensitiveHeaders: Cookie,Set-Cookie,Authorization` configuration. It can be overridden, but you need to be sure that you are not leaking sensitive information in cookies down stream:

```
 zuul:
  routes:
    users:
      path: /myusers/**
      sensitiveHeaders:
      url: https://downstream
```

But first you need to read why they are disabled in the Spring Cloud documentation:

> You can share headers between services in the same system, but you
>   probably do not want sensitive headers leaking downstream into
>   external servers. You can specify a list of ignored headers as part of
>   the route configuration. Cookies play a special role, because they
>   have well defined semantics in browsers, and they are always to be
>   treated as sensitive. If the consumer of your proxy is a browser, then
>   cookies for downstream services also cause problems for the user,
>   because they all get jumbled up together (all downstream services look
>   like they come from the same place).

http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/single/spring-cloud-netflix.html#_cookies_and_sensitive_headers